# Correlation between two aggregate timeseries

Tags: regression, correlation

I am currently engaged in research to find out whether there is a relationship between the number of photo count and the number of visitors coming for whale watching.

The first dataset (photo count) is small (approximately 198), while other dataset (no of visitors) are in thousands. Both datasets collected per month basis. My question is can I correlate this dataset each other? I am bit hesitant because of the variable size ranges of data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Correlation requires pairing the data.

Comment: with your data, it is allowed to run a correlation. You can pair your variables, because for every photo count you have number of visitors. And if you have variance in both of your varibales, an existing correlation will be dedected by a correlation-test. But you should consider conducting a regression-test. A linear regression will show you how much more visitors you will have by adding one foto.

Comment: ...and not only - as it is the case for a correlation test - if there is a dependency between your variables. And dont forget to plot your data in a scatter chart. "Viewing" your data gives you a good opportunity to detect patterns. I wouldnt wonder if the number of visiors increased with number of photos, but since a specific number of photos was reached, it wouldnt affect the number of visitors anymore (Tradeoff).

Comment: @Tharindu when you say photo counts are "small" do you mean only 198 counts over all? This is a relatively large number by most accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can cross-correlate the two time series by merging the monthly counts for either measure and calculating a correlation between their logged values. If

You must, of course, know which month and year either aggregate data has. If they do not overlap, then such data cannot probably be analyzed this way (or any way).

This is an ecological design, poorly controlled, so very little information if any can be attained from such an analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note (the other comments seem to have answered your question): You are analyzing count data, which is often not normally distributed. Be aware that the pearson correlation coefficient might not be suitable in your case, since it assumes normality. You might need to move to a more robust correlation coefficient (e.g., Spearman's)

Comment: Some of these remarks are questionable or false: many count data are very well modeled by a Normal distribution (especially with counts exceeding 100 or so) and the pearson $\rho$ makes no distributional assumptions whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry, if my statements should be false. But pearsons coefficient is based on first and second momentum statistics (it's based on covariance), which *can* be a problem, depending on the underlying distribution. Count data is often (but not necessarily) heavily skewed, which can affect the estimation of correlation, hence my remark. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Robustness)